# Generate artifical sales data series in R with arima model & add noise

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I'm extremely new to R and pretty new to time series analysis. I have been looking for the answer online but I can't seem to find it.

I need to generate an artificial time series that would represent sales data of a product X. I need to make a few variations. an Independent series (I can do that with Excel), and a series with AR(1) with rho= 0.8, and with added noise level.

For the AR(1), I know I can use

```
ar.sim<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(.8)), n=52)
ar.sim
```

this generates 52 data points along the lines of

```
 [1] -2.080871400 -1.327156528 -0.672868162  0.521280151 -0.200243250
 [6]  0.808095642  2.208014641  4.266957623  1.682261358  0.796715498
```

Question 1: How do I make it start from a certain level, e.g. from 300 products sold? I thought n.start but that seems to be something else.. Do I just add 300 everytime? that seems wrong..
Question 2: How can I add noise to this series?

Comment: Your question has answer here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6958/simulation-of-arima-1-1-0-series.

Comment: Aha, the e is the error in that answer, so the noise, thanks. That series still starts at 0 though?

Comment: Did you try something like `arima.sim(n=52,model=list(ar= c(.8)), start.innov=300,n.start=1)`?

Comment: Hm, then it starts at 300 and just goes down to 0 where it starts the sin wave. so it looks like a (reversed) log function.